# Install old version of Jasmine with NPM

Tags: npm, jasmine

I need to run some unit tests on version 1.3.1 of Jasmine for some test to pass
Unfortunately, it seems NPM doesn't see versions prior to 2.0.0
These oldies are available from [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/jasmine-core/versions) for example

**Is NPM able to fetch versions from "external" URLs?**

Comment: In my case the root problem was a version discrepancy between karma-jasmine which includes jamine 1.3.1 up to a certain version where it relies on jasmine-core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like versions of `jasmine` prior to 2.0 were not published to the `npm` registry:

```
$ npm info jasmine
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine

{ name: 'jasmine',
  description: 'Command line jasmine',
  'dist-tags': { latest: '2.1.1' },
  versions: [ '2.0.1', '2.1.0', '2.1.1' ],
```

When I check out the jasmine sources from github, I do not see a `package.json` (needed for npm install) in the branch for 1.3.x :

`$ git clone https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine -b 1_3_x
$ cd jasmine
$ ls -la package.json
ls: package.json: No such file or directory`

`npm` requires a package.json file to install, so you cannot use `npm` to install old versions of `jasmine`.